# ListView With Multiple Text and Images

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I am trying to display text and images in a List format then also in 6 separate tabs but I have 10 different combos like this:

1.(text,image)
2.(text,image,image)
3.(text,image,text,image)
4.(text,image,text,image,image)
5.(text,image,text,image,text,image)
6.(text,image,text,image,image,image)
7.(text,image,text,image,image,text,image)
8.(text,image,text,image,text,image,text,image)
9.(text,image,text,image,text,image,text,image,text,image)
10.(text,image,text,image,text,image,text)

So there will be different combos of text and images in each tab. What is the best way to do this other than making 10 different layout files for each text and image combo

Pic below of how it should look. This is only text but images will be put in

[image]

Comment: please share your design image.

Comment: you have to make visible gone view for that

Comment: Add code of what you've done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make only 1 layout containing all the textviews and images possible with `setVisibility(View.GONE)` and then on your condition, display the corresponding ones with `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`